# Regex: How to detect a pattern if an undesired sub pattern comes before the pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to use Java to detect a sequence of either: lowercase, uppercase, or digits, but not JUST digits separated by periods.
Restriction: No consecutive periods.

The sample String I have is: `@@@951.324.1@@@foo1.bar2.123proccess.this.subString`

I currently have the following regex: `((\p{Alnum})+\.)+(\p{Alnum})+`

I'm trying to have the pattern recognize `foo1.bar2.123proccess.this.subString` but my regex gives me `951.324.1` since it's a sub-pattern of the pattern I defined.

How would I go about detecting the subString `foo1.bar2.123proccess.this.subString`

I would imagine the general nature would be: The entire returned String should have at least 1 lowercase or uppercase char, but I'm hopelessly confused on how I would detect that in the String.

Comment: Is `123.abc` a match?

Comment: Yes. So in your case :@@@951.324.1@@@123.abc , return 123.abc

Comment: Are you after [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wzgal5/1)?

Comment: Yess sir!!! Thank you for help! But one more restriction is that I want it to have at least 1 period. So at least 2 sequences

Comment: @Pvo See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-zA-Z\d.]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d.]*
```

This can be split into 3 parts:

```
[a-zA-Z\d.]* // optional sequence of letters/numbers/dots
[a-zA-Z] // MUST have a letter
[a-zA-Z\d.]* // optional sequence of letters/numbers/dots
```

Basically, "sandwiching" things that are required in optional things.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/VT4t2x/1

Comment: That's a great answer, but how would you proceed in restricting the regex to not accept consecutive periods, and that periods should go only in between the sequences(cannot end or start with period)? If there are consecutive periods or the sequence starts or ends in a period, no match should be found.

Comment: Also, what if I want at least 1 period, which means I need at least 2 sequences?

Comment: @Pvo If you have that many more requirements, I suggest you use your original regex and just check whether there are letters in each match programmatically, using `charAt` and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
String rx = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+|(\\p{Alnum}+(?:\\.\\p{Alnum}+)+)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wzgal5/5) (pattern adjusted since regex101 does not support Java POSIX character class syntax)

The point is to match and skip dot-separated digit chunks, and only match and capture what you need. See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/VelKnQ):

```
String s = "@@@951.324.1@@@abc.123";
String rx = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+|(\\p{Alnum}+(?:\\.\\p{Alnum}+)+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    }
}  // => abc.123
```

Comment: What if I had a case like: '@@@951.324.1@@@abc.123' or  '@@@951.324.1@@@123.abc'?

Comment: @Pvo I modified the solution. It will find a match in all cases but when the `xxx.xxx.xxx` is all digits and dots.

Comment: This is the exact same problem I've been having though. The rx you provided detects xxx.xxx.xxx is all digits.

Comment: @Pvo Yes, but that is where Java comes in and discards them. This is the only safe and correct way to do what you want *in a single step*. Otherwise, you would still need to get all of those matches and later filter out those `match()`ing `"\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+"`